# Android Simple Calculator

Tags: java, android, textview, calculator

I am new to android app development, and I am working on a simple calculator. 
[image]

The MainActivity.java file is as follows-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    View substract = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Substract);
    substract.setOnClickListener(this);
    View multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Multiply);
    multiply.setOnClickListener(this);
    View divide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Divide);
    divide.setOnClickListener(this);
    View equals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Equals);
    equals.setOnClickListener(this);
    //Numbers
    View nu1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n1);
    nu1.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n2);
    nu2.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n3);
    nu3.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n4);
    nu4.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n5);
    nu5.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n6);
    nu6.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n7);
    nu7.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n8);
    nu8.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n9);
    nu9.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nu0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.n0);
    nu0.setOnClickListener(this);
    View ac = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AC);
    ac.setOnClickListener(this);
    View ce = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CE);
    ce.setOnClickListener(this);
    View del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DEL);
    del.setOnClickListener(this);
    View pnt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.np);
    pnt.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    float num1=0,numx=0;
    int choice=0;
    TextView num = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Number);
    num.setOnClickListener(this);
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Add:
            choice=1;
            numx=num1;
            num1=0;
            num.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.Substract:
            choice=2;
            numx=num1;
            num1=0;
            num.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.Multiply:
            choice=3;
            numx=num1;
            num1=0;
            num.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.Divide:
            choice=4;
            numx=num1;
            num1=0;
            num.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.Equals:
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    num1=numx+num1;
                    num.setText(""+num1);
                    choice=0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    num1=num1-numx;
                    num.setText(""+num1);
                    choice=0;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    num1=num1*numx;
                    num.setText(""+num1);
                    choice=0;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    num1=num1/numx;
                    num.setText(""+num1);
                    choice=0;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    num.setText(""+num1);
                    choice=0;
                    break;
            }
        case R.id.n1:
            num1=num1*10+1;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            System.out.print(num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n2:
            num1=num1*10+2;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n3:
            num1=num1*10+3;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n4:
            num1=num1*10+4;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n5:
            num1=num1*10+5;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n6:
            num1=num1*10+6;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n7:
            num1=num1*10+7;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n8:
            num1=num1*10+8;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n9:
            num1=num1*10+9;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
        case R.id.n0:
            num1=num1*10;
            num.setText(""+num1);
            break;
    }


}
```

}

I face the 2 problems-

1. If I want to enter any number more than one digit it doesn't happen. Like if i press 53, first the textview shows 5.0 then 3.0
2. Secondly, all the calculations always give output 1.0 after pressing the = button

Can anyone, help me out!

Comment: can you please post xml code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting a click listener on num?

You are defining the choice, and clicked numbers in the `onClick` method and reinitializing them every time you click one of the buttons. These should be part of the activity fields

Comment: So, it cannot be done by implementing OnClickListener? I have to call OnClick() for each button in the OnCreate method?

Comment: It can be done. I just don't understand why are you setting that click listener "num.setOnClickListener(this);". And I pointed out that your variables are initialized each time that you click a btn. for example when you click on equals the choice would be 0

Comment: I removed the num.OnClickListener(), it was a mistake.I get what you are saying. I just thought using the switch case in onClick() seemed better than calling onClick() for each button. Is there anyway i can Implement onClickLitener and the values dont get initialized each time? A static specifier or something?

Comment: What he meant by the 2nd paragraph is to move those local variables outside the method: put `float num1=0,numx=0;int choice=0;` above the `@Override protected void onCreate()`. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) for more information.

Comment: Got It....Totally a stupid mistake. I keep forgetting that Android coding properties are the same as that of Java and  C++! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

You must get the text for your textview **num** in the switch cases(add,sub).Like `num.getText().toString().`

Comment: Why is that necessary? The number is stored in num1, and when add or any operand is pressed, num1 is copied in num x, and num 1 is set to 0. So next time on pressing of a digit, the second number is entered in num1. And pressing = adds num1 and numx.

Comment: The number is stored in num1...you are telling that the number you are inputting in your textview is stored in num1...right??but where is that code??

Comment: @kgandroid OP is right. The `TextView` only displays the number while those numbers are stored inside 2 `float` variables. There is no need to use `num.getText().toString()` in this case.